# javascript format date from DDMMYYYY to DD/MM/YYYY

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime, datepicker

I have a datepicker and I want to parse the date to dd/mm/yyyy when user input is ddmmyyyy.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JUtaQ.png)

I have add a javascript function to the input text but I don't know if I am on the right way

```
<inputText id="input1" onchange="parseDate()"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
         $("#input1").datepicker()   
    };
    function parseDate() {
        ??? 
    }
<script>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that's the exact format you're looking at, then you could just parse it out:

http://jsfiddle.net/q3yrtu0z/

```
$('#input1').change(function() {
  $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/^(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{4})$/, '$1/$2/$3'));
});
```

This is designed such that if the value is exactly 8 digits, then it will format it XX/XX/XXXX.

You may want to do additional validation on the validity of the date format (although you'd have to do this for MM/DD/YYYY inputs as well anyway)

Answer (score 0):

As you're going for a simple transformation, consider [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice)ing your *String* to the points where you want to add your characters, for example

```
var strA = '13102015',
    strB = strA.slice(0, 2) + '/' + strA.slice(2, 4) + '/' + strA.slice(4);
strB; // "13/10/2015"
```

As this may be invoked multiple times if the user modifies it later, you may also wish to force the input into expected formatting at the start using [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace), e.g.

```
'13/102015'.replace(/[^\d]/g, ''); // "13102015"
// now continue to slice
```

In a *RegExp*,

- `[chars]` means match these characters (in this case `c`, `h`, `a`, `r`, `s`)
- `[^chars]` is the inverse of `[chars]`, i.e. match any character except these characters
- `\d` is any digit, i.e. the numbers `0` to `9`
- The `g` flag means `g`lobal, i.e. after a match keep looking for another match

Answer (score 0):

Try this....

```
function convertDate(inputFormat) {function pad(s) { return (s < 10) ? '0' + s : s; } var d = new Date(inputFormat); return [pad(d.getDate()), pad(d.getMonth()+1), d.getFullYear()].join('/'); }
```